# How can I write SQL query to enter data into this database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got a food menu which needs to have a pattern for when certain menus are displayed on a website.

For example, the pattern is split into *yearly quarters*, *weeks* and *days*.

```
**Quarter 1**
**Week 1**
Monday: 5
Tuesday: 4
Wednesday: 5
Thursday: 4
Friday: 6
Saturday: 7
Sunday: 7
```

The numbers represent the *ID* of the menu in the database.

So I have *4 quarters*, *4 weeks* and *7 days* in the database. This is how it's laid out:

[image]

I don't get how to write the query to update the database, say for example I want to update the following:

I want to put *Menu Number*: 4, In Week 1, Quarter 1 on a Thursday? That is based off what they select on a HTML Checklistbox.

[image]

Comment: I think there is something wrong in the logic, you should have 4*12 weeks and 366 days!

Comment: if theres more then 4 weeks it will loop back to week 1 until the next quarter, thats not a problem i just cant figure out how to add the data in the correct place

Comment: Does parent_id represent the menu number?

Comment: In general, in relational database to perform update you must know at least one field value to update according to it.

Answer (score 0):

For your example the query could be something like this.

```
UPDATE menuset
SET thursday = 4
WHERE week = 1
AND quarter = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you

```
update tablename SET monday=$monday WHERE week=$week AND quarter=$quarter
```